# node Cron with callback getting Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, cron

I am trying to query DB in particular interval. So I am using node corn. I am creating a connection every minute and close it once query completed. but it works only for a first minute, next minute it throws an error of Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit, even I am using a callback. Some one correct what I am doing wrong

app.js

```
var sController = require('./sController');
 cron.schedule('* * * * *',function(){
  console.log("I am running every minute");
  var params ="dddd";
  sController.updateDb(params,function(err,res){
  console.log("xxxx");
 });

});
```

sController.js

```
var sModel = require('./smodel');
var sController = function(){}

sController.prototype.updateDb = function(params,callback){
    sModel.updateDb(params,function(res,err){
        if(res){
            console.log("kkk");
        }
        callback(err,res);
    });
}
module.exports = new sController();
```

smodel.js

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(mysqlConfig);
function mysqlConnect() {
    connection.connect();
}
function mysqlClose() {
    if(!connection._protocol._ended){
        connection.end();
    }
}
var sModel = function() {};

sModel.prototype.updateDb = function(params,callback){
    updateDb(params, function(err, res) {
        callback(err,res);
    });
};
function updateDb(params,callback){
    var query = 'SELECT * from tablename';
    mysqlConnect();
    connection.query(query,function(err,rows,fields){
        if(!err){
            console.log(rows.length);
        }
         callback(err,rows);
    });
    mysqlClose();
}

module.exports = new sModel();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer

you should use mysql connections Pool. look into offical doc https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

long answer

server take enough time & resource to create connection. pool save connection instance and reuse. see info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool